# How to import css to only one component?

Tags: css, angular

I need to import ignite-ui styles only for one component.

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detailed-report',
  templateUrl: './detailed-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detailed-report.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

Css:

```
@import "../../../../../../../../node_modules/igniteui-angular/styles/igniteui-angular.css";
```

or

```
@import "~igniteui-angular/styles/igniteui-angular.css";
```

This does not work. However, if I change `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` the styles are applied. However, if I go to other components, these styles are applied to them also. I need to apply styles only for one component

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detailed-report',
  templateUrl: './detailed-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './detailed-report.component.css',
    '../../../../../../../../node_modules/igniteui-angular/styles/igniteui-angular.css' // make sure it's the right path
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

or switch to `scss` and import it in the styles file

```
@import "~igniteui-angular/styles/igniteui-angular.css";
```

`css` don't have import statements

Comment: or use webpack to use @import

Comment: any ideas why the first approach doesn't work? Works only with ViewEncapsulation.None

Comment: Angular views are encapsulated by default [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) also not all browsers supports shadow DOM check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) to see how it's working

Comment: I'm using chrome, ShadowDom works for simple styles, but doesn't for this imported one

Comment: So, when you add your `css` file to `styleUrls` does it work?